# Asus K52F laptop web camera shows upside-down picture in Skype

Tags: 11.10, skype, webcam, asus

How to fix upside-down picture produced by web camera in Asus K52F (1.3 Mpix, don't know the model) laptop (Intel i3 M350, Intel video, Ubuntu 10.10) ?

Update: It seems ridiculous :) but the "upside-down issue" is continuing even in Ubuntu 11.10. I am pretty sure it's a Skype prob (2.2.0.35 beta from official Ubuntu partner repository.)

Comment: The following command set has helped:  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libv4l/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade. Yet, it works only in Cheese. Skype continue to show a flipped picture.

Comment: You should try using your laptop upside-down :D J/K ...lol

Comment: Sometimes I do :)

Comment: for me this solution here worked http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8925031&postcount=225 , the only thing I had to change was location of v4l1compat.so library because on my Ubuntu 11.10 it is in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/`, to check where it is on your computer type `locate libv4l` in terminal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoting Hans de Goede:

> Hi,
>
> Try using the latest libv4l which has a (constantly updated) list of know to have an upside down webcam laptop models. Installation instructions are here:
>   http://radu.cotescu.com/2009/11/05/flipped-images-ubuntu-webcam/
>
> If that does not work your laptop model is not in the list of libv4l, please do (as root):
>
> ```
> lsusb > lsusb.log
> dmidecode > dmi.log
> ```
>
> And send me <hdegoede@redhat.com>, a mail with the 2 generated files attached. Do *NOT* copy and paste them I need them 100% unmodified.
>
> I'll then add your laptop to libv4l's upside down table and get back to you with testing instructions.
>
> Regards,
>
> Hans

---

You can see [here](http://git.linuxtv.org/v4l-utils.git?a=commitdiff;h=7f17a3a6a59b1ef1e0cb6b35d558aa45dca4dc5a), that your laptop model has been added to the the latest version of libv4l.

Now you either need to test it (instructions in above link), or wait for Ubuntu to update that package (which, I guess, won't happen for Ubuntu 10.10).

Comment: The quoted link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the procedure described here works for your case:

http://swik.net/Ubuntu/Only+Ubuntu/How+to+fix+upside+down+webcam+image+in+ubuntu/cnw5h

Answer (score 1):

My laptop is the same as yours. I followed htorque's solution, the only difference is that when you call skype the command `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype` doesn't work because the folders are different.

Using the following instead I can see the webcam in the right mode:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib32/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype
```

Answer (score 0):

after reading this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=838210 you should fix problem.

recent posts are related to Ubuntu 10.4 LTS but it should work also in 10.10 :)

Comment: It refers to 2008-generations of Ubuntu, so I think there should be easier way to fix such a problem in 2010 :)

Comment: @Vincenzo Sometimes with hardware problems the solution will always take some degree of work. I'd recommend still giving it a shot and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Install an app called **v4l2ucp** and use the tilt option to rotate the output of your webcam. It doesn't work for me; I guess my Cam doesn't support it.

```
sudo apt-get install v4l2ucp
```

Comment: Hi Owais, thanks for the hint. Preview in v3l2ucp works well, Skype continues showing flipped picture :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some patches for the Asus k52f... I have just used the video patch and it repaired the Skype reverse image issue on my unit (once again).

http://www.korecky.org/?p=307&langswitch_lang=en

Good luck.