# My webcam is upside down whenever I use it

Tags: drivers, video, asus, webcam

Tried googling, didn't work. So, I'm using ubuntu 13.04. My webcam is an integrated ASUS.
And I don't really know what I'm doing. If there is some software that would allow me to, like flip my video (Like many cam for ubuntu) or some command that I could use that would just intercept the data from my webcam and flip it then I'd love you.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/12718/asus-k52f-laptop-web-camera-shows-upside-down-picture-in-skype and http://askubuntu.com/questions/327191/webcam-upside-down-when-using-skype for possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is that webcam often is mounted upside down.  It is a driver job to reverse the image, so if you have this kind of problem it means there is something from with the webcam driver.  If you use Linux, I suggest to follow this [HOW-TO](http://forum.ubuntu-it.org/viewtopic.php?p=1326411#p1326411)  The site is in Italian, you can see an English translation [Here](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http://forum.ubuntu-it.org/viewtopic.php?p=1326411#p1326411).